# Opening Insert Hyperlink in Excel 2010 in a Specific Folder

Tags: excel, vba

We're having a problem with the Insert Hyperlink problem taking *forever* to populate because of a ton of files in a network folder (Windows 7, xp was fine... oh the good old days.  And yes, I've tried everything, disabling search, different reg entries, etc... and I'd like a different and less hacky solution.)

What I'm looking for is a macro that prompts for a number (in this case a client file number), and then opens the Insert Hyperlink dialogue inside a specific folder (for example, the file number the user enters might be 4321, and then the insert hyperlink dialogue would be opened inside the folder z:\clients\4321\  It's the z:\clients folder that has a stupid number of folders in it)

The actual file that would be hyperlinked would be somewhere inside there, so additional browsing would have to be done by the user.  And I'm not sure exactly how the macro would behave in so far as knowing what to hyperlink (presumably the current cell would make sense to me).

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: I actually found something that deals with this online (I thought I'd done my research!) so I though I'd post it rather than deleting my question.

This macro seems to do exactly what I want.  Well, it doesn't prompt for the file number and then go into that folder, but the dialog it DOES bring up doesn't suffer from the SO SO slow issue of population taking minutes.  It populates within a second!


Sub QuickLink()
ChDrive "z:"
ChDir ("z:\clients")
File = Application.GetOpenFilename
If File <> False Then
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:=File
End If
End Sub

Comment: I can't answer my own question yet  =).  I'll log in later tonight to do so if someone else hasn't!

Answer (score 0):

... You may have to play around with it a bit, but your best bet is probably to set the `Hyperlink Base` for each user's sheet and then set relative hyperlinks in the sheet itself.

Hope this helps...